# Tabhost with view pager, ClassCast error

Tags: view, fragment, pager

I have an activity which populates a scroll view for each day of the week and display them with tabs made on the action bar using view pager. Whenever I go back to a tab that I had already visited I get a class cast error.
This is my log cat. Can someone please tell me why this exception is caused.

```
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

08-23 05:01:50.589:E/AndroidRuntime(3836):java.lang.ClassCastException:android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.widget.CompoundButton$SavedState
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.onRestoreInstanceState(CompoundButton.java:379)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:12284)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2626)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2626)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2626)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2626)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2626)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:12262)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:425)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:949)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:550)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:509)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:490)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at com.example.attendogram.Start.onTabSelected(Start.java:195)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:572)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:1098)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:547)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-23 05:01:50.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3836):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In searching for answers, I came across this post.
[Unexplainable ClassCastException in android.widget.ProgressBar.onRestoreInstanceState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298184/unexplainable-classcastexception-in-android-widget-progressbar-onrestoreinstance)

In all of our cases, android.view.AbsSavedState$1 was being cast to some other component.

The accepted answer says that the problem is the application is reusing ids.

"Double check that your application does not reuse the same ID in two different places"

If you are using eclipse, the Lint tool can be helpful in tracking down the duplicate id. [image]. I hope this helps.