# ClassCastException occur when screen orientation change (AbsSpinner)

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-orientation

My custom Activity has two spinners.
I wait for the view create done and try rotate the device but my app crashed.
I have already tried some methods that I searched here, but cannot fix this problem.

**LogCat**

```
12-16 16:15:47.200: D/AndroidRuntime(5332): Shutting down VM
12-16 16:15:47.200: W/dalvikvm(5332): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40154760)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{qt.r07/qt.r07.listview.FileSelectActivity2}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsSpinner$SavedState
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3188)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1028)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
**12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsSpinner$SavedState**
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onRestoreInstanceState(AbsSpinner.java:421)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:8316)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchThawSelfOnly(ViewGroup.java:2038)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(AdapterView.java:766)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2024)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2024)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2024)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2024)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2024)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2024)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2024)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:8295)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1512)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:898)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:870)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1099)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1793)
12-16 16:15:47.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5332):     ... 12 more
```

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Tiger 20141211 -->
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/file_manager_frame" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/file_manager_linear"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/FrameLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/FrameLayout3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/text_view_office"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="地政事務所"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="32sp" />

                    </FrameLayout>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/FrameLayout4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/text_view_section"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="地段"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="32sp" />

                    </FrameLayout>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/FrameLayout5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/text_view_land_no"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="地號"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="32sp" />

                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/FrameLayout6"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spinner_office"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:background="#FFC8E6C9" />
                    </FrameLayout>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/FrameLayout7"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spinner_section"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:background="#FFC8E6C9" />
                    </FrameLayout>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/FrameLayout8"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout5"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/edit_text_land_no"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:ems="10"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"
                                android:inputType="number|text"
                                android:maxLength="9"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="32sp" >

                                <requestFocus />
                            </EditText>

                            <Button
                                android:id="@+id/button_land_no_add"
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/file_manager_button_oval"
                                android:text="+"
                                android:textColor="#FFC8E6C9"
                                android:textSize="32sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="地號列表"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="32sp" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/FrameLayout9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/list_view_land_no"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#FFC8E6C9" >
                </ListView>
            </FrameLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_file_manager_ok"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/file_manager_button_rectangle"
                android:text="確定"
                android:textColor="#FFC8E6C9"
                android:textSize="32sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Code**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.filemanager_r07);

    ...

    adapter_office = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.drawable.file_manager_spinner, office_list);
    spinner_office = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_office);
    adapter_office.setDropDownViewResource(R.drawable.file_manager_spinner_dropdown);
    spinner_office.setAdapter(adapter_office);
    spinner_office.setId(0);
    spinner_office.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    adapter_section = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.drawable.file_manager_spinner);
    showMapFileList(MAP_PATH + "/AA"); // adapter_section content add in this method
    spinner_section = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_section);
    adapter_section.setDropDownViewResource(R.drawable.file_manager_spinner_dropdown);
    spinner_section.setAdapter(adapter_section);
    spinner_section.setId(1);
    spinner_section.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    edit_text_land_no = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text_land_no);
    button_land_no_add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_land_no_add);
    button_land_no_add.setId(1);
    button_land_no_add.setOnClickListener(this);
    list_view_land_no = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view_land_no);

    button_file_manager_ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_file_manager_ok);
    button_file_manager_ok.setId(10);
    button_file_manager_ok.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: You might want to tell us on which line of code the exceptions occurs... As this is not (clearly) obvious from you question: You are trying to cast something to `SavedState`, whereas there is no `(SavedState)` (or something similar) in your provided code! Also, `onRestoreInstanceState()` seems to be missing in your example code, which is the method where the exception occurred.

Comment: It's just fine when I rotate the device and reentry the onCreate method. I have try to use debugger to trace the process and find out when process run out of onRestoreInstanceState method, the exception occur. As you mean is that I should add onRestoreInstanceState method to cast SavedState? (btw, I am Asian...so please forgive my English...)

Comment: I mean that `android.widget.AbsSpinner.onRestoreInstanceState(AbsSpinner.java:421)` is missing from the provided code. This line throws the exception, so without it we cannot help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unexplainable ClassCastException in android.widget.ProgressBar.onRestoreInstanceState](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298184/unexplainable-classcastexception-in-android-widget-progressbar-onrestoreinstance)

Comment: Veger: thanks for your answering, I'll found out how to add and use onRestoreInstanceState() method later. Sufian: I'll try this solve later too, thanks~