# How to test saving and restoring state of an android activity with Espresso?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

Is there a way of testing the save and restore state code of an activity programmatically ? I mean doing this :

[How to test code built to save/restore Lifecycle of an Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533517/how-to-test-code-built-to-save-restore-lifecycle-of-an-activity) but in an automated way.

I have tested `activity.recreate()` method which is almost what I am searching, but in fact it does not reset the fields of my activity like if I was killing the process. So my test can pass even if I don't implement the restoring things in my `onCreate` method (since my fields are unchanged...).

I am currently playing with Espresso v2 and I was wondering if this could be possible maybe by playing with the `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to use the `activity.recreate()` method BUT do not forget to follow this by an assertion which waits for an idle state.
My problem with my first attempt was that the test I was writing was like :

```
instrumentation.runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        activity.recreate();
    }
});
assertThat(activityTestRule.getActivity().getXXX()).isNull();
```

Where `XXX` was a field that I expected to be null when no save/restore state handling had been implemented. But that was not the case because my assertion was not waiting for the recreation task to be completed.

So in my situation, my problem was solved when I simply add an espresso assertion which does the job, for example by verifiying that the TextView which displayed the `XXX` field was empty.

Finally, thanks to the UI thread synchronization provided by Espresso, my test which can assert on my activity save/restore state missing implementation can be written like :

```
instrumentation.runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        activity.recreate();
    }
});
onView(withText("a string depending on XXX value")).check(doesNotExist());
```

Note that the rotation solution suggested does the job either, but can be much slower than `activity.recreate()` when we just want to test the activity lifecycle. And in my case it was not relevant since my activity was not implemented for a landscape orientation.

Answer (score 4):

You can rotate the screen and verify that the state is saved and restored properly.

```
private void rotateScreen() {
  Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
  int orientation 
    = context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

  Activity activity = activityRule.getActivity();
  activity.setRequestedOrientation(
      (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) ?
          ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE : 
          ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Full example: http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/10/espresso-save-and-restore-state.html

Comment: It is a nice solution, but in fact I have an application which run only in portrait mode, so it cannot be applied to my test since it does not change the orientation...

Answer (score 1):

The testing tools offered by Android now offer a means of writing UI tests that can recreate an activity to test the save and restore flow. See the [Recreate the activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/testing#recreate) section within the [Test your app's activities](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/testing) Android Developers documentation page. An example of the syntax – taken from that page – is the following:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyTestSuite {
    @Test fun testEvent() {
        val scenario = launchActivity<MyActivity>()
        scenario.recreate()
    }
}
```