# Android Espresso test save and restore instance state

Tags: android, android-espresso, onsaveinstancestate, onrestoreinstancestate

I try to test Activity's instance state save and restore in Espresso.

How to test the full life cycle? 
The suggest at 
[How to test saving and restoring state of an android activity with Espresso?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926643/how-to-test-saving-and-restoring-state-of-an-android-activity-with-espresso)
 is helping already, but how can we test the Parcelable `writeToParcel / createFromParcel` stuff? (means when InstanceState is not just saved and restored but serialized in between, which is causing this nice "Unmarshalling unknown type code" exceptions if code does not work)

[Destroy and restart Activity with Testing Support Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35306423/destroy-and-restart-activity-with-testing-support-library) test rule does not keep instance state.

I experimented a bit with `getInstrumentation().callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(oldActivity, stateBundle);` but no success.

Any idea?

Comment: This answer has the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63465944/9636

Comment: The solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63465944/6937282 does not completely answers this question because it does not use `createFromParcel`. See comment there.